# Some questions about bday paradox results

Tags: c#, birthday-paradox

I need someone to correct me or to discuss with me, why are my results of a 23 person calculation of the bday paradox always ~65%. It is said it should be ~50%, but whatever I do, I receive this result.

What I ask is someone to explain to me what I did wrong and correct me, or explain to me (if I'm good) why are my results as they are.

The little program I made is here: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RW3OCD)

Could some see it and point out what they think?

Thanks! Hope you all have a great day.

EDIT: Thanks for the feedback! Issue was that I only cleared the list when the dupe was found and was resolved by moving the "clear" line outside of the if condition so it runs after every iteration.
Now the results are constant, and around 50%.
Cheers!

Comment: please include all information relevant to your question ***in your post***, not hosted on external sites.

Comment: also: you only clear your `intList` (terrible naming, btw) _if_ you get a collision. so, if you don't get one, you simply add new values, effectively testing 46 people in the next test round. i recommend packaging your code into simple, testable methods to reduce errors like this.

Comment: `for(int u = 0; u < runTests; u++, intList.Clear())` to clear the list after *each* experiment

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EuKQtD and you'll get something like `50.41% (theory: 49.27%)`

Comment: @FranzGleichmann i watched a video about the paradox, wanted to try it out, and got abnormal results. The naming does its purpose well within the quick test I made, imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you clear up the list only in cases when dupes are found. For non-dupe cases the list keeps growing increasing probability of the dupes in the next iterations.